# Encoding in Dataweave transformer for UTF-8?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

In dataweave transformer even after setting the output encoding as "UTF-8". The chinese characters are getting changed.
Could you please help suggest how to set the encoding UTF-8 for dataweave transformer. sample values are as below. if i set the Dfile.encoding in .ini file it is working but i want to achieve it using different way as the applications are deployed in cloud.
永康大灣**永康區大灣路796號1樓**

Before DW: 永康大灣

After DW: "æ°¸åº·å¤§ç�£

Answer (score 1):

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8"
---
payload
```

NOTE: unicode literals are not supported yet

Comment: I've explicitly set it also. but still transformation is occurring. one strange thing which we observed is if we send charset in header explicitly to UTF-8. it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

For transforming the special chars like as Japanese chars 永康大灣永康區大灣路796號1樓 you need to check the encoding of the input file and if input file has encoding as 'UTF-8' then it will not create the problem in conversion of these special chars.

Required encoding of input file is 'UTF-8' for handling of such chars.